# React.JS-organize bulk input by new lines

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I created this bulk input which get's several strings and divided by newlines:
[image]

Each line need's to be classified into an object/ array, and there is no option to enter them one by one.
The problem here is that each line has to contain 2 commas or 3 commas (3 or 4 strings per one line) and I don't have a clue how to solve it.
Is someone have any idea how to deal with it?

Main Code:

```
 handleChange=(event)=>
    {
        this.setState({value: event.target.value})
    }
 sendForm=()=>
    {
        this.toggleModal();
        this.inputBulk();
    }
splitCommas=(bulkedValue)=>
    {
        let splittedArr=[];
        let splitedObj={};
        splittedArr=bulkedValue.split(',',3);
        console.log(splittedArr);
    }
render(){
return(
  <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="comment">Bulk Upload</label>
        <textarea className="form-control" rows="30" value={this.state.value} id="comment bulk" onChange={this.handleChange}></textarea>
        </div>
)}
```

In addition, I'm using Node.JS in my back hand.

Many Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I found the split('\n') function and it works perfectly so this question can be closed.

Thank you!